# Wrapping text after zooming in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

When I pinch zoom the page in Google Docs to make the text bigger, the text does not reflow/recalculate the wrap, so I cannot read the document without panning left/right to view the whole line.

This is an issue as I would like to use Google Docs on my tablet for presentation notes when I present.

Comment: I guess it's by-design. Google Docs (like Microsoft Word, etc) is a document-writing service used for printable reproduction, so wrapping the word when zooming is not the right idea. That said, your workaround works though.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:** Select all text and set the font size bigger (20pt worked for me) then zoom out so the whole line is visible.  The text will still be quite large.